# Drop the shadow behind the dialog box using css/ jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to drop a shadow / blur the background of the `div id = "test"` dialog box, I have tried using the jquery ui provided class .ui-widget-shadow / .ui-widget-overlay but it doesn't seem working properly. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

```
  <style>
    div {
        display: none;
        width: 90%;
        height: 95%;
        margin-left:5%;
        background: #ccc;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    div img {
        display: inline;
        margin-left:5%;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button>show the div</button>
<div id = 'test'> <img src = 'image.png'></div>

<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $( "div" ).show( "scale", 180 );
});

$( "#test" ).dblclick(function() {
    $( "#test" ).hide( "scale", 200 );
});

</script>
```

Comment: #test {box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You haven't done anything related!

If you need a `drop-shadow` for the `#test`, then you can use this CSS:

```
#test {box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #000;}
```

You can generate the code using many [online `box-shadow` generators](http://css3generator.com/).

Else, if you need something like a **modal window**, which hides or blurs the background, you need to add another `div` and give `z-index`, etc. You can see more information from: [Simple jQuery Modal Window Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial).

Comment: LOL. Very strange. coincidence?

Comment: Impossible. Same Values? This is freaky!

Comment: Ha ha... Donno... Should be coincidence... You know, great minds think alike! :)